# Printing Visual with WPF

Tags: wpf, printing

I have a paginator for visuals. The problem is that when i create the visual from code i have to call Measure and Arrange. But i want to give them infinity value.

```
  stackpanel.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
  stackpanel.Arrange(new Rect(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity)));
```

This causes

> Cannot call Arrange on a UIElement with infinite size or NaN. Parent
>   of type 'System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel' invokes the UIElement.
>   Arrange called on element of type
>   'System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel'.

Answer (score 3):

In the `Measure` step, a parent asks its children how much space they desire given a certain amount of space. This amount of space can also be **infinity**, which would mean to ask the children 'how much space would you like? There is no limit.'

In the `Arrange` step the elements are physically arranged on the layout. A parent tells its children where they are arranged and how much space they get. However the size parameter of the Arrange function **cannot be infinity** because this is the actual size the element will have.

Do you use Infinity because you want the visual occupy all the available space on printed page?
If yes what I usually do is that

```
Size sz = new Size(printCapabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth, 
             printCapabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight);
//update the layout of the visual to the printer page size.  
yourElement.Measure(sz);
yourElement.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(printCapabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginWidth, printCapabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginHeight), sz));
```

Comment: when i call measure only ,the size is 0 height/actualheight. Is something i can do for this?

Comment: actually i want to find the real dimension that it would take because i have a paginator that would cut the visual into pieces.I dont want to limit it at page size. The problem is that after calling arrange says it is X height (its real height it would take).No matter what rect i gave it returns the correct real dimensions.(visual.ActualHeight) The problem is that although dimensions are real nothing is printed if i dont call arrange second time with actual dimensions.